# Windows PowerShell - How to switch back to a suspended SSH connection

Tags: linux, windows, networking, ssh

I've established a SSH connection to my LAN laptop running Ubuntu Server from my desktop running Windows 10 using PowerShell 7. I've ran some tasks, then suspended the session with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>. I know that in Linux environment the command to reconnect to a suspended SSH connection is <kbd>fg</kbd>. Apparently, this doesn't work in Windows.

Does someone know what the correct command is in Windows environment?

Comment: Well, might try the opposite of Ctrl+z: Ctrl + Y ?

Comment: @Dr_Xunil tried the mentioned combination, but didn't switch back to the session.